# How to create YouTube live videos?

Tags: video, youtube

The main title is overly-simplified. Let me explain what I exactly mean:

First, check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljQsRLN2dXA) live video.

What I want to know is that what software go into creating such a kind of live video. Some of the elements that pop out are the looped video + animation on lower left side that reacts to music + music of course.

Let me know what all software I'd require.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This question is off topic here, asking for product / service / learning material recommendation. Please read what's [on-topic here](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with any software that can stream to youtube.

I used for such scope [OBS](https://obsproject.com/), that allow you to stream your desktop, programs or whatever on your pc. To reach that behaviour you just have to create a new live video from youtube dashboard, then use the `stream name` obtained in youtube, and paste it in obs stream key, in options.

Than you set up your pc to reproduce it, like creating a playlist in vlc, and stream only vlc trhought OBS.

Note that that's only one of the solutions you can find out, but that worked for me.